# How to show "Copy" menu for a table cell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I would add the option to copy the selected cell in a table like in the contacts app.

[image: copy menu]

I have tried to follow [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2488237/3308310) about Objective-C and impliment those methods in Swift:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, shouldShowMenuForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}

override func canPerformAction(action: Selector, withSender sender: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
    return (action == #selector(NSObject.copy(_:)))
}
```

However, that is an old question, and I can't get the menu to show up using *Swift* code.  Could someone explain how the `shouldShowMenuForRowAtIndexPath` method is used and how to allow for a user to copy a cell.

Comment: Here's an existing answer in Swift: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36327412/9044237

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You refer to [an Objective-C example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2488237/3308310), but you have not done what it says to do! Your second method is the wrong method. You want to say this:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canPerformAction action: Selector, 
    forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath, withSender sender: AnyObject?) 
    -> Bool {
        return action == #selector(copy(_:))
}
```

You will also need a third override:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, performAction action: Selector, 
    forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath, withSender sender: AnyObject?) {
        // ...
}
```