# iOS create "copy paste" like popover (UIMenuController) in UITableView

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

Im trying to create a intractable pop over similar to how apples "copy", "paste". Im not sure how to do it.

[image]

Is there a 3rd party lib or is it a native component ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2487844/simple-way-to-show-the-copy-popup-on-uitableviewcells-like-the-address-book-ap ?

Comment: Do you want to use it on label ?

Comment: @SagarShirbhate want to use it on table view cell

Comment: For PopOver You can use any thirdParty Popovers (Or Using UIPopOver in iPAD[in iphone by Making Category]) and For Copy use   [[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard] setString:copiedStr];

Comment: @caughtinflux thanks for the ref. but my question is to create the popover it self.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it helps anyone, the keyword to look for is "UIMenuController"

I finally managed to solve this by implementing a custom UITableViewCell

```
override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {

        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
        let showPasswordItem = UIMenuItem(title: "Show Password", action: #selector(showPass(_:)))
        let copyUserNameItem = UIMenuItem(title: "Copy Username", action: #selector(copyUsername(_:)))
        let copyPasswordItem = UIMenuItem(title: "Copy Password", action: #selector(copyPass(_:)))
        self.isPasswordShowing = !self.password.isSecureTextEntry
        UIMenuController.shared.menuItems?.removeAll()
        UIMenuController.shared.menuItems = [copyPasswordItem,copyUserNameItem,showPasswordItem,hidePasswordItem]
        UIMenuController.shared.update()

        if selected {
            self.becomeFirstResponder()
            let menu = UIMenuController.shared
            menu.setTargetRect(self.contentView.frame, in: self.contentView.superview!)
            menu.setMenuVisible(true, animated: true)
        }
    }

override func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {

     return  action == #selector(showPass(_:)) || action == #selector(copyUsername(_:)) || action == #selector(copyPass(_:))

}

override var canBecomeFirstResponder : Bool {
    return true
}

func showPass(_ send:AnyObject){
    self.password.isSecureTextEntry = false
    self.isPasswordShowing = true
}
func copyUsername(_ send:AnyObject){
    UIPasteboard.general.string = self.username.text
}
func copyPass(_ send:AnyObject){
    UIPasteboard.general.string = self.password.text
}
func hidePass(_ send:AnyObject){
    self.password.isSecureTextEntry = true
    self.isPasswordShowing = false
}
```