# Does iOS 13 - UIMenu have a bug that doesn't show its image?

Tags: swift, uitableview, ios13, uimenu, uiaction

Paste the following code into a project:

No image shows next to 'Device Honey' ie the `UIMenu`
However the image shows up next to 'Copy' ie the `UIACtion`.

Am I doing something wrong? If this is a bug? Is there a workaround?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let tableview: UITableView = {
        let tv = UITableView()
        tv.frame = UIScreen.main.bounds

        return tv
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.addSubview(tableview)
        tableview.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        tableview.delegate = self
        tableview.dataSource = self
    }
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        if cell.detailTextLabel == nil {
            cell = UITableViewCell(style: .value1, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
        }
        cell.textLabel?.text = "Honey"
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "iOS developer"

        return cell
    }

    @available(iOS 13.0, *)
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, contextMenuConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath, point: CGPoint) -> UIContextMenuConfiguration? {

        return UIContextMenuConfiguration(identifier: nil, previewProvider: nil, actionProvider: { suggestedActions in

            return self.makeContextMenu(for: indexPath)
        })
    }

    @available(iOS 13.0, *)
    func makeContextMenu(for indexPath: IndexPath) -> UIMenu? {

        let copyAction = UIAction(title: "Copy", image: UIImage(systemName: "square.and.arrow.up")) { [weak self] _ in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            let cell = self.tableview.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
            let pasteboard = UIPasteboard.general
            pasteboard.string = cell?.detailTextLabel?.text
        }

        guard let cell = self.tableview.cellForRow(at: indexPath), let title = cell.textLabel?.text else { return nil}
        return UIMenu(title: "Device \(title) ", image: UIImage(systemName: "square.and.arrow.up"), children: [copyAction])
    }
}
```

[image]

In Apple's WWDC demo they're able to do it as shown below:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A context menu has two parts: the preview and the menu. Both are optional. The "groceries" thing in the Apple screenshot is the *preview*, not the menu. By default, the cell is snapshotted and the snapshot is displayed as the preview. The menu itself in the Apple screenshot has no image and no title. And that's what you should do too! The last line

```
return UIMenu(...
```

...should have no title and no image. This menu, the one that wraps everything else and is returned, is the *top-level* menu, and it is displayed differently (as your own screenshot shows). It looks best without a title, and it cannot display an image at all. Its job is to wrap everything else and to provide an identifier, and that's all.

You will then get something like this:

[image]

Comment: Then how is Apple doing the ‘groceries’ title and the image? Obviously my title is showing....

Comment: "The top level" that was key. Is that mentioned anywhere in the API? Can you include that in your answer?

Comment: and I suppose there's no built-in class that I can just assign a title and image. Right?

Comment: I do not know what that means. You mean you want to create the preview yourself? Of course you can do that.

Comment: I was asking if just like tableviewcell where you just dump the image and text and the layout is done, is there anything similar for the PreviewProvider? I rather not create it myself :)

Comment: I still don't know what you mean. The table view cell _is_ the preview by default.

Comment: I don't know what you mean either!

Comment: Oh. Well, your Apple snapshot shows it. The table cell that you long pressed has been snapshotted and the snapshot is used as the preview. And that is the default behavior. So there is nothing to "create".

Comment: And your own screenshot is doing the same thing. Your cell is the preview.

Comment: ‍♂️I get it now. Thanks. Problem was that my cell itself didn't have an image, but I wanted to add the image to the previews. I wasn't thinking straight

Comment: I added a screencast.

Comment: Can you take a look [How can I use suggestedActions given from UIContextMenuConfiguration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58456587/how-can-i-use-suggestedactions-given-from-uicontextmenuconfiguration)?

Answer (score 0):

<sub>This is more of an important comment</sub>

The preview that you're showing in your question is terribly misleading. It looks like the other items in the menu. Yet that Groceries section in your screenshot is a **Preview**. A much more distinctive preview would be something like this:

[image]

[Image source](https://www.fivestars.blog/code/uicontextmenuinteraction.html)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same question, documentation on UIMenu init(title:image:identifier:options:children:) indicates an image parameter:

> image:
> The image to display next to the menu's title.

It looks like is intended to be used in submenus, as shown in this blog:
[UIMenu Comprehensive Guide](https://nemecek.be/blog/88/uimenu-comprehensive-guide)