# How can I use suggestedActions given from UIContextMenuConfiguration?

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios13, uiaction, uimenu

Other than the a [WWDC video - 44:18](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/224/?time=2658) a [sample project](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicommand/adding_menus_and_shortcuts_to_the_menu_bar_and_user_interface?language=objc) there's not much info online.

> So the `actionProvider`, when called, has a list of `suggestedActions`
>   that are passed to it by the system.
>
> This can be a mix of `UIMenu`s and `UIAction`s, so potentially a fully
>   constructed hierarchy that are picked up from the system. These could
>   be things that you defined in your responder chain using the new UI
>   command API being introduced in iOS 13 or things that are offered by
>   other system components. So we're doing a fully custom menu here, so
>   we're going to put the `suggestedActions` aside. First, we'll create
>   our edit menu.

But so far what I've learned is that <s>a given Identifier can have pre-defined suggestedActions</s> the `suggestionActions` are not associated with any identifier. If I change that identifier the `suggestedActions` won't change. It seems to be based on its context, which here I'm guessing I'm in the context of a tableviewcell...

I'm trying to see what it looks like, but nothing shows up. If I tap on the cell nothing shows up.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let tableview: UITableView = {
        let tv = UITableView()
        tv.frame = UIScreen.main.bounds

        return tv
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.addSubview(tableview)
        tableview.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        tableview.delegate = self
        tableview.dataSource = self
    }
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        if cell.detailTextLabel == nil {
            cell = UITableViewCell(style: .value1, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
        }
        cell.textLabel?.text = "Honey"
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "iOS developer"

        return cell
    }

    @available(iOS 13.0, *)
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, contextMenuConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath, point: CGPoint) -> UIContextMenuConfiguration? {

        return UIContextMenuConfiguration(identifier: nil, previewProvider: nil, actionProvider: { suggestedActions in
            print("suggestedActions", suggestedActions)
            let menu = UIMenu(title: "", children: suggestedActions)

            return menu
        })
    }
}
```

I've also printed `suggestedActions`, what I got out was:

```
  - 0 : <UIMenu: 0x6000008e6790; title = Standard Edit; identifier = com.apple.menu.standard-edit; options = (Inline); children = <NSArray: 0x600001318900>>
  - 1 : <UIMenu: 0x6000008e6820; title = Replace; identifier = com.apple.menu.replace; options = (Inline); children = <NSArray: 0x6000008e64c0>>
  - 2 : <UIMenu: 0x6000008e7330; title = Text Style; identifier = com.apple.menu.text-style; image = <UIImage:0x60000349c870 symbol(system: bold.italic.underline) {36, 17} baseline=3.66667,contentInsets={1, 2, 1, 2},alignmentRectInsets={-2.9999999999999982, 0, -0.33333333333333348, 0} config=<(null), traits=(UserInterfaceIdiom = Phone, DisplayScale = 3, DisplayGamut = P3, HorizontalSizeClass = Compact, VerticalSizeClass = Regular, UserInterfaceStyle = Light, UserInterfaceLayoutDirection = LTR, PreferredContentSizeCategory = L)>>; children = <NSArray: 0x6000008e6df0>>
  - 3 : <UIMenu: 0x6000008e6d00; title = Lookup; identifier = com.apple.menu.lookup; options = (Inline); children = <NSArray: 0x60000049c870>>
  - 4 : <UIMenu: 0x6000008e7060; title = Learn; identifier = com.apple.menu.learn; options = (Inline); children = <NSArray: 0x60000049c220>>
  - 5 : <UIMenu: 0x6000008e6d90; title = Speech; identifier = com.apple.command.speech; options = (Inline); children = <NSArray: 0x6000008e6490>>
  - 6 : <UIMenu: 0x6000008e7180; title = Share; identifier = com.apple.menu.share; options = (Inline); children = <NSArray: 0x60000049c6a0>>
  - 7 : <UIMenu: 0x6000008e6a30; title = Writing Direction; identifier = com.apple.menu.writing-direction; options = (Inline); children = <NSArray: 0x6000006fe1c0>>
```